# Visual Studio files included in git commits even when excluded using .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bitbucket, gitignore

I have a large VS solution, under Git source control using Atlassian BitBucket.

The .gitignore file contains lines to exclude build results (int the /obj and /bin) directories, but these keep showing up in my changes.

The .gitignore file contains the following lines, could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

Comment: When using VS, use VS. AFAIK VS will ignore that file and use its project settings. So you will have to configure ignored files in VS itself.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but VS itself takes me to the .gitignore file when I go to Team Explorer --> Settings --> Repository Settings. It lists it as the "ignore file", so I would be very surprised if it ignored the ignore file!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that these files were added to the repository before the patterns were added to the `.gitignore` file. When a file is in the repo, it is never ignored, even if it matches a pattern in `.gitignore`. To remove the files from the repo, use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: Thanks, that's got most things, how would I remove, from the solution level (i.e. repository root), all of the contents of /{project}/obj and /{project}/bin ?